# ¿Es posible optimizar esta consulta?

Tags: sql

soy nuevo en esto, tengo un ejercicio de bases de dato en el que se me pide seleccionar un elemento de un campo (articulo) que tenga mayor cantidad de otro campo(cliente) sin repetir, en mysql logre hacerlo pero parece una consulta poco eficiente, quería saber si me pueden decir como mejorarla, la consulta es la siguiente:

```
SELECT  articulo FROM comenta 
    GROUP BY articulo, cliente
    HAVING COUNT(*) = (
SELECT MAX(contador) As maximo FROM (
        SELECT articulo, COUNT(cliente) As contador FROM (
            SELECT articulo, cliente FROM comenta
                GROUP BY articulo,cliente) aS t
                group by articulo
                having COUNT(cliente))As t);
```

y la tabla sobre la que trabaja es esta:

[image: Tabla]

Desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Podrias explicar que trata de hacer u consulta, datos de entrada, que esperas como salida? no se entiende bien tu query

Comment: ¿Por qué te parece poco eficiente? A priori no parece que tenga nada poco eficiente. Otra cuestión es que dé vueltas innecesarias pero, para averiguarlo, tienes que seguir las indicaciones de @gbianchi y pasarnos el dataset para hacer las pruebas de velocidad, ver el execution plan y, sobre todo, saber qué pretendes conseguir y a partir de qué datos